# pyqt5 stop bug when I run my code at Windows 10 environment

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a problem recently . I begin to use pyqt5 as my GUI . I find this problem and I couldn't find any information about it .OK here we Go .

I cannot ran this code .

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import cv2
import qimage2ndarray as q2n
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication , QMainWindow

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 480)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 220, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 480, 360))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pyqt5_button_clicked)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))

    def pyqt5_button_clicked(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        a = cv2.imread("1.jpg")
        while(1):
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            image = q2n.array2qimage(frame)
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
            self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
            cv2.waitKey(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But the strange thing is if I add this line into the while(1) loop the code can work .

```
cv2.imshow("webcam", frame)
```

And at other system like ubuntu it can work normally.please tell me what's wrong with my code thank you .

Comment: Please fix your code indentation, and consider reducing this to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I checked again and I didn't find any indentation issue . it's just a little pyqt program so I don't know how to reduce this code . if you run it ,and push the button it will crash .thank you very much .